# Quickest way to create a correlation matrix based on matching characteristics of observations in a data.table

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

Any quicker ways to do this?  First time posting, sorry if I get formatting incorrect.

```
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
dt.assignedCorrelations = CJ(group = c(TRUE, FALSE), type = c(TRUE, FALSE), class = c(TRUE, FALSE), sign = c(TRUE, FALSE))
dt.assignedCorrelations$corr = sample(seq(0,1,0.01), size = nrow(dt.assignedCorrelations), replace = TRUE)

num.obs = 1e4
dt.characteristics = data.table(group = sample(seq(1, 25, 1), size = num.obs, replace = TRUE),
                                type = sample(c(1,2), size = num.obs, replace = TRUE),
                                class = sample(c(1,2), size = num.obs, replace = TRUE),
                                sign = sample(c(1,2), size = num.obs, replace = TRUE))

mat.correlations = sapply(seq(1, num.obs), function(num.row){
  dt.characteristicsOfInterest = dt.characteristics[num.row]
  dt.binary = data.table(group = dt.characteristics$group == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$group,
                         type = dt.characteristics$type == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$type,
                         class = dt.characteristics$class == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$class,
                         sign = dt.characteristics$sign == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$sign)
  
  num.correlations = merge(dt.binary,
                           dt.assignedCorrelations,
                           sort = FALSE,
                           by = c('group', 'type', 'class', 'sign'))$corr
  
  return(num.correlations)
})
```

I am trying to create a correlation matrix as efficiently as possible where each correlation is based on the agreement of a set of characteristics.  In order for my application to be viable, I would like to have this computation sped up by at least an order of magnitude from where it is right now, which is around 15 seconds (ideally an upper bound of 0.5 seconds).

Using mclapply does speed it up substantially, to around 7 seconds, but adding cores does not seem to help much beyond that.

```
mat.correlations = simplify2array(mclapply(seq(1, num.obs), function(num.row){
  dt.characteristicsOfInterest = dt.characteristics[num.row]
  dt.binary = data.table(group = dt.characteristics$group == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$group,
                         type = dt.characteristics$type == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$type,
                         class = dt.characteristics$class == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$class,
                         sign = dt.characteristics$sign == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$sign)
  
  num.correlations = merge(dt.binary,
                           dt.assignedCorrelations,
                           sort = FALSE,
                           by = c('group', 'type', 'class', 'sign'))$corr
  
  return(num.correlations)
}, mc.cores = 8))
```

I also tried calculating only the lower triangular matrix including the diagonal, which cuts the number of comparisons by slightly less than half, but after taking into account the added time needed for the matrix creation and transposition for the upper triangular, it was not much faster.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I’m voting to migrate this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

1. Your data of 1000 rows has only 200 unique rows, so as a start you're calculating duplicate results for a 5x slowdown. If we group by data, we can reduce this.
2. Your creation of `dt.binary` is really just an inner join of `dt.characteristicsOfInterest` and `dt.characteristics`, we can optimize that code to something more `data.table`-canonical.

When I ran your code on my computer, it took 87 seconds:

```r
st <- system.time({
  mat.correlations = sapply(seq(1, num.obs), function(num.row){
    dt.characteristicsOfInterest = dt.characteristics[num.row]
    dt.binary = data.table(group = dt.characteristics$group == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$group,
                           type = dt.characteristics$type == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$type,
                           class = dt.characteristics$class == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$class,
                           sign = dt.characteristics$sign == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$sign)

    num.correlations = merge(dt.binary,
                             dt.assignedCorrelations,
                             sort = FALSE,
                             by = c('group', 'type', 'class', 'sign'))$corr

    return(num.correlations)
  })
})
st
#    user  system elapsed 
#   11.17    2.14   87.08
```

Compare with this calculation in 1.65 seconds:

```r
st2 <- system.time({
  out <- list()
  ign <- dt.characteristics[
  , grp1 := {
    this <- as.data.table(Map(`==`, dt.characteristics[, .SD, .SDcols=names(.BY)], .BY))[
      dt.assignedCorrelations, corr := i.corr, on = c("group", "type", "class", "sign")]
    out <<- c(out, list(this$corr))
    .I[1]
  }, by = c("group", "type", "class", "sign") ]
  mat.correlations2 <- do.call(cbind,
    out[match(dt.characteristics$grp1, sort(unique(dt.characteristics$grp1)))])
  dt.characteristics[, grp1 := NULL]
})

st2
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.15    0.05    1.65 

identical(mat.correlations, mat.correlations2)
# [1] TRUE
```

we get a ~50x speed improvement (this one run).

If we do a larger benchmark,

```r
bench::mark(
  mat.correlations = sapply(seq(1, num.obs), function(num.row){
    dt.characteristicsOfInterest = dt.characteristics[num.row]
    dt.binary = data.table(group = dt.characteristics$group == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$group,
                           type = dt.characteristics$type == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$type,
                           class = dt.characteristics$class == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$class,
                           sign = dt.characteristics$sign == dt.characteristicsOfInterest$sign)
    num.correlations = merge(dt.binary,
                             dt.assignedCorrelations,
                             sort = FALSE,
                             by = c('group', 'type', 'class', 'sign'))$corr
    return(num.correlations)
  }),
  mat.correlations2 = {
    out <- list()
    ign <- dt.characteristics[
    , grp1 := {
      this <- as.data.table(Map(`==`, dt.characteristics[, .SD, .SDcols=names(.BY)], .BY))[
        dt.assignedCorrelations, corr := i.corr, on = c("group", "type", "class", "sign")]
      out <<- c(out, list(this$corr))
      .I[1]
    }, by = c("group", "type", "class", "sign") ]
    do.call(cbind, out[match(dt.characteristics$grp1, sort(unique(dt.characteristics$grp1)))])
  }
)
# Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                  memory                   time           gc              
#   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                  <list>                   <list>         <list>          
# 1 mat.correlations     1.57m    1.57m    0.0106    11.3GB    0.318     1    30      1.57m <dbl [10,000 × 10,000]> <Rprofmem [517,772 × 3]> <bench_tm [1]> <tibble [1 × 3]>
# 2 mat.correlations2    2.48s    2.48s    0.404    993.8MB    0.404     1     1      2.48s <dbl [10,000 × 10,000]> <Rprofmem [9,889 × 3]>   <bench_tm [1]> <tibble [1 × 3]>
```

we can see a 38x improvement in `` `itr/sec` ``, and 1/11th the memory consumption (`mem_alloc`).